# Change response body on android

Tags: java, kotlin

I am new to android app development. Tell me which library will be easier to use to replace body in response.Sorry for bad english. If I didn’t express myself clearly, I’m looking for an analogue of Fiddlercore, namely the rules function with which you can change the received requests.

I looked through several libraries but didn't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

okHttpInterceptor allows you to add interceptors so you can modify requests & responses. you can add multiple interceptor to okHttp client.

Charles Proxy & Mitmproxy are not libraries, but can provide what you need.
hope this helps.